# How to get only the required tags from XML using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

If I have a XML with huge header tags but I need to get only the list of objects dppc and child object ppc. Please advise how to get the values only from the node dppc.

```
<SOAPENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAPENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<SOAPENV:Body>
    <rpc:distributeObject xmlns:SOAPENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:rpc="http://company.xxx.com/Distributed/Object">
        <standardHeader xmlns="http://wsi.nat.bat.com/2005/06/StandardHeader/">
            <dppc>
                <ppc>
                    <productName>Export1</productName>
                </ppc>
                <ppc>
                    <productName>Export2</productName>
                </ppc>
            </dppc>
        </standardHeader>
    </rpc:distributeObject>
</SOAPENV:Body>
```

Please find the below code to unmarshal it

```
String example =

                      "<SOAPENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAPENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:SOAP-ENC=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><SOAPENV:Body><rpc:distributeObject xmlns:SOAPENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:rpc=\"http://company.xxx.com/Distributed/Object\"><standardHeader xmlns=\"http://wsi.nat.bat.com/2005/06/StandardHeader/\"><dppc><ppc><productName>Export1</productName></ppc><ppc><productName>Export2</productName></ppc></dppc></standardHeader></rpc:distributeObject></SOAPENV:Body>";


message = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null,
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(example.getBytes()));
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Dppc.class).createUnmarshaller();
Dppc dppc = (Dppc)unmarshaller.unmarshal(message.getSOAPBody().extractContentAsDocument());
dppc.getPPC();

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Dppc{
@XmlPath("rpc:distributeObject/standardHeader/dppc")
private List<PPC> ppC;


    public List<PPC> getPPC() {
        return ppC;
    }


    public void setPPC(List<PPC> ppC) {
        this.ppC= ppC;
    }
}
class PPC {
       String productName;
        //getter & setters;
}
```

I have created a package-info file also, but it is not working.

Comment: your xml seems to have errors..post it again

Answer (score 0):

With the pure Implementation of JAXB this is not possible because JAXB don't support XPath by default.

One possible solution is to use [EclipseLink(MOXy)](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy) which supports the `@XmlPath` Annotation.

With that annotation it is possible to define the Path of an Element inside the XML. For your XML to read only the `dppc` Elements and childs your class would look something like this (not tested):

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement(name="SOAPENV:Body")
public class MainElement{
    @XmlPath("rpc:distributeObject/standardHeader/dppc")
    DPPC dppc; 

    //getter and setters
}
```

Same for the `dppc` and `ppc` class.

The Link to MOXy give you some nice examples.

Comment: After adding the code i am getting the error, Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", local:"Envelope"). Expected elements are <{}SOAPENV:Body>

Comment: Added POJO's also

Comment: The `@XmlPath("<Path>")` annotation is missing on the value of DPPC like i showed in my little code examle.

Comment: I have added as you have suggested I am not getting the anything. Could you please let me know why I am not getting the value

Comment: what did you have added to the pojo class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150714/discussion-between-user3428736-and-kevin).